Help understanding degenerate conic discriminants.
So a conic section is the solution to polynomials of the form:
$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$
OK makes sense, but what determines a "degenerate" conic?
On Wikipedia (and a couple other websites and blogs) it says that a Parabola of the form $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dxz+2Eyz+Fz^2$ forms a matrix:
$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
A&B&D\\
B&C&E\\
D&E&F
\end{bmatrix}$
And that the discriminant to determine if a conic is degenerate is the determinant of the matrix.
Namely "a conic is degenerate $\iff \det(Q)=0$"
OK.
Why is there a 3rd variable $z$ in the polynomial? Why are $B$, $D$, and $E$ now $2B$, $2D$, and $2E$? How can I relate this to the first polynomial equation without "$z$'s" and "$2$s".
And does this have any importance to the shape of conic determinant $B^2-4AC$?

Last section of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO2zAU3Eppo

Your original equation has matrix $Q'=\begin{bmatrix}
A&\frac{B}2&\frac{D}2\\
\frac{B}2&C&\frac{E}2\\
\frac{D}2&\frac{E}2&F
\end{bmatrix}$ as you can see by multiplying out ${\bf x}^t Q'{\bf x},$ where ${\bf x}=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix}.$ The homogeneous form with $z$ not necessarily $1$ is from projective geometry. The rank of the matrix $Q'$ is the full three when the determinant is non-zero. \begin{bmatrix}
A&\frac{B}2\\
\frac{B}2&C
\end{bmatrix} however can have determinant $0$, that's when you get a parabola.
In projective geometry, when the rank of $Q'$ is two, you get a line pair, when the rank is $1$ you get a double line. In affine (usual) geometry the line pair can be two parallel lines, etc.
